# Accessing Private iOS Apis, How to?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-privateapi

I would like to access some private APIs from the iOS SDK, related to the Camera like:

```
- (void)setExposureMode:(int)arg1;
- (int)exposureMode;
```

Etc. This is only for my personal development and I don't plan on submitting any Apps to the store. But I can't seem to figure out how to access and use these APIs. Is there any tutorial or book explaining the procedure?

For example, I tried adding this line to my .h file:

```
@interface AVCaptureDevice (Private)

- (void)setExposureMode:(int)arg1;

@end
```

But when I call this API from my App, it crashes. Even though respondsToSelector returns TRUE.

So could anyone link me to some good resources to learn about private API programming?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing is syntactically almost correct.

The only issue is that in your category declaration you are using `int` instead of `float`. You might try and change this and see if things improve but I suspect the problem lies elsewhere.

With private API, no description is available about the way its methods should be used. So, maybe you are calling a method at the wrong time or in the wrong context. Possibly inspecting the crash log could give some insights.

One more thing, looking at your crash: possibly the fact that it is crashing is because the exposureMode you set is not supported. Try and use ([ref](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html)):

```
- (BOOL)isExposureModeSupported:(AVCaptureExposureMode)exposureMode
```

to check it before hand (if your are not doing it already).

Comment: I am sorry I copied the wrong API, I am actually using setExposureMode not setExposureGain. So I don't think there is a problem with the int/float. I will try to check the logs..

Comment: I checked the logs this is what I get:0   CoreFoundation                 0x37d1b29e __exceptionPreprocess + 158
1   libobjc.A.dylib                0x3581b97a objc_exception_throw + 26
2   AVFoundation                   0x39cbd9ec -[AVCaptureFigVideoDevice setExposureMode:] + 548 any idea what this means?

Comment: as far as I can read, `setExposureMode` is called; then `setExposureMode` throws an exception. we can not know why from the log: may be a wrong argument; maybe some previous call was expected to set things right, etc...

Comment: OK so that's some run-time issue, but my syntax to access private APIs is in itself correct and is not the root cause of the exception?

Comment: this is what I read from the crash log... `AVCaptureFigVideoDevice` is likely not properly set up at the moment of the call, but the call is executed...

Comment: OK thanks a lot for your response, I'll look into the set up

Comment: I have found this: http://pastie.org/pastes/1467719 -- maybe it will be of some help...

Comment: Thanks a lot sergio! There are a couple of things wrong with my question, setExposureMode is actually public anyway but the thing is that you need to call lockForConfiguration and unlock before and after it. But for other private APIs I suspect the same thing holds..

Comment: @Sredni: if you found my answer up to the point suggesting that some precondition was not met when calling a private API, don't forget to accept the answer. thanks.