# iPhone private API compiling

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, iphone-privateapi

I'm searching through the whole internet since a few hours now, and I just can't find the informations I'm looking for.
I would like to mess around with the private apis, see whats possible, etc., but I can't even compile something.

So I've got a few pretty basic questions:

- Do I have to dump the headers? Because I downloaded a sample, where the API is loaded with

```objc
char *framework = "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/...";
dlopen(...);
```

I would like to use the objc-syntax (if possible) rather than using C (as mentioned above), if there are any opportunities.

- How do I make Xcode compile, if I import the private APIs? Do I have to add other link flags? (because I read about two different opinions)
  I added a private framework and created a new Folder "Headers" and put all the headers files in there, so the framework shows up correctly in Xcode. Do I have to import the whole .framework, or only the headers from the framework I would like to use? After I imported the framework, I get 20+ errors, unknown type names, and many more.

And, finally, I've read about entitlements (which seem to be new in iOS 7). How do I use these entitlements and when do I use them?

Could someone please just type a few lines as an example?

Comment: what do you mean by private APIs? Do you mean APIs that exist in the system, but are not public? or do you mean third-party APIs that you can download like the Facebook SDK?

Comment: I mean the APIs that exist but are not public, like Apple80211, MusicLibrary.framework, etc

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986849/accessing-private-ios-apis-how-to?rq=1

Comment: Sorry, but this does not help.
Could someone just say what exactly I have to do?
1. Import the header file you want
2. set XY as link flag in settings
3. etc.
?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Background

In order to use methods in *any* framework, you can choose to either reference those frameworks statically or dynamically.  I haven't seen anything in your question that suggests you need to use *dynamic* linking, so I'm going to avoid that (it's slightly more complicated for a beginner). (‡)

To statically reference APIs in a framework, you would import the relevant headers, and then configure your Xcode project to link to the framework.  These two steps only change *slightly* for **Private** APIs.

Private APIs usually don't provide you with the headers (*.h) that describe the APIs.  I say "usually", because sometimes, an API that's private on iOS is actually public on Mac OS X, so to use it, you simply copy the OS X version of the header into your project.

### Generating Headers

Probably more common, though, is that you have to **generate** the header yourself.  If you know which header you need, often you can find it posted [online under someone's github account](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers).  If not, you need a tool like [class-dump](http://stevenygard.com/projects/class-dump/), or [class-dump-z](https://code.google.com/p/networkpx/wiki/class_dump_z).  Run the class dump tool on the private framework, by finding it on your Mac:

```sh
cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/
class-dump -H -o ~/Headers/7.0/MusicLibrary/ MusicLibrary
```

Then, go into `~/Headers/7.0/MusicLibrary/` and find lots of dumped header files.  Copy (only) the header(s) you need into your Xcode iOS project directory.  Then, from inside Xcode, right click on a source folder in your Project Navigator view, select **"Add files to <Project Name> ..."**.  Pick the dumped header file you need to include in your project.

### Linking

In order to successfully link against the API, you also need to add the framework to your Xcode Build Phases.  From your project **Target** settings, select **Build Phases** then **Link Binary with Libraries**.  You normally choose a public framework from the default list that the iOS SDK provides you.  However, you can choose to browse your Mac for 3rd-party frameworks, or private frameworks, too.  For private frameworks, you're just going to have to navigate to a folder location like this

```sh
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/
```

and then pick the `*.framework` directory.

Then, simply use the APIs like you would use any public/private API.  `#import` the header file, call the APIs, instantiate the classes, etc.

The use of this code:

```objc
char *framework = "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/...";
dlopen(...);
```

is an attempt to **dynamically** open a private framework.  That's not necessary, if you know at compile time which framework you want to use, and have it present on your Mac to let Xcode link against.

### Entitlements

Entitlements are not new to iOS 7.  They have existed for quite some time, and are one technique iOS uses to prevent unauthorized usage of some private APIs.  iOS will check to see if your app has been granted a particular entitlement (by name), and if it does not have that entitlement, calling the protected API will fail (usually *silently*, although sometimes you'll see a message in the Console log).

[See here for an example of granting your (jailbreak) app an entitlement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14885266/119114).

---

**(‡) Update:** iOS 9.3 has brought some changes with respect to Private APIs, and static vs dynamic linking. Please [see this Stack Overflow question here for more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37001091/119114).

Comment: awesome answer, thank you! The point I wasn't understanding was the linking process. Great!

Comment: Has any of this changed for iOS 9+?  I actually don't see the "PrivateFrameworks" directory inside of the SDK/System/Library dir. The SDK for the Simulator contains the PrivateFrameworks, but when including that (and running on simulator), I still get an `ld` error that the framework can't be found

Comment: @Kevin, yes, unfortunately, it changed in iOS 9.3. Please see my [response to this recent question here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37001091/119114).