# unable to find SBLockScreenNotificationScrollView.h file in Springboard API

Tags: objective-c, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi, cydia-substrate, logos

I'm working on an cydia substrate tweak and I have this line of code:

```
double threshold = [SBLockScreenNotificationScrollView scrollThresholdForPasscodeScroll];
```

When I try to compile I'm getting these errors and warnings for the line.

[image]

I've imported `<Springboard/Springboard.h>` in my file and it's coming from `/opt/theos/include`. I've also tried importing `<SBLockScreenNotificationScrollView.h>`, but it's unable to find the file. I'm a bit lost here and any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: I've tried using [these](https://github.com/thomasfinch/iOS-7-SpringBoard-Headers) headers instead, but they give me a whole bunch of errors, too many for the compiler to list.

Comment: `id` is a generalized object pointer, while `double` is a "scalar".  Never the twain shall meet.  But in this case the more significant error (and cause of the first) is that the compiler hasn't a clue what SBLockScreenNotificationScrollView is, presumably because you haven't included the .h file.

Comment: Maybe you used a forward class declaration in your .h file, and didn't #include it in your .m file???

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to figure out is why I can't find the SBLockScreenNotificationScrollView.h file. The title is a bit misleading. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause here is that the API you want to use is a **Private** API.  If you want to include a file such as `SBLockScreenNotificationScrollView.h`, you'll need to acquire or generate that header file, and put it into your project manually.  That file doesn't get automatically delivered with Theos/Logos, or the iOS SDK.

Probably the easiest thing to do is to run [class-dump](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstevenygard.com%2Fprojects%2Fclass-dump%2F&ei=BMATU8D0F4-DogTN4YKYCA&usg=AFQjCNGLfSzH92NJDqueuLvsOlLOgeQ9cg), or [class-dump-z](https://code.google.com/p/networkpx/wiki/class_dump_z), to reverse-engineer that header file.  The class dump should be run on the `SpringBoard` executable itself.  SpringBoard is an app (not a framework), that lives on the iPhone at `/System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/SpringBoard`.  So, if your device is jailbroken, and you have `openssh` installed, you can ssh into the device (or use `scp`) to transfer the executable to your Mac:

```sh
scp root@iphone-ip-address:/System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/SpringBoard .
```

Then, run class dump on the executable:

```sh
class-dump-z -H SpringBoard
```

and you'll get a huge set of header files in the current directory, including SBLockScreenNotificationScrollView.h.

You'll probably then notice that your header depends on another header, which depends on another header.  If you try to build, you'll often encounter build errors that are frustrating to chase down.  My recommendation would be to cut out all the stuff you don't need from the header that contains the private methods you want.  Those private headers, when included in your project, don't need to be a **complete** specification of the private classes (e.g. the `SBLockScreenNotificationScrollView` class).  They just need to contain a minimal description of the interfaces you're trying to call, to satisfy the compiler.

### Example

This pruned header would probably be sufficient for you (noting what I've commented out):

```objc
//#import "UIGestureRecognizerDelegate.h"
//#import <XXUnknownSuperclass.h> // Unknown library

//@class SBLockScreenNotificationCell;

@interface SBLockScreenNotificationScrollView /* : XXUnknownSuperclass <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> */ {
//        SBLockScreenNotificationCell* _associatedCell;
}
//@property(assign, nonatomic) SBLockScreenNotificationCell* associatedCell;
+(float)scrollThresholdForPasscodeScroll;
@end
```

*Note: after that, if you're getting linker errors, there's probably more you'll need to do.  I recommend posting another question on theos/logos linker errors, show the error output, and someone may be able to help you.  That way, we keep each question narrow and specific.  Thanks!*

### References

[iPhone private API compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21970650/119114)

Answer (score 0):

Error messages seem to be non-helpful--at first anyway. But they usually are informative but it takes some studying to learn how to interpret the. The worst for most people are linker messages but they are also informative, it just takes some studying.

Let's look at them:

`double threshold = [SBLockScreenNotificationScrollView scrollThresholdForPasscodeScroll];`

> Receiver 'SBLockScreenNotificationScrollView' for class message is a forward declaration

There is only a forward declaration, probably `@SBLockScreenNotificationScrollView` The actual declaration of the class `SBLockScreenNotificationScrollView` and it's method `scrollThresholdForPasscodeScroll` need to be seen by the class (.m file).

> No known class method for selector 'scrollThresholdForPasscodeScroll'

The method `scrollThresholdForPasscodeScroll` is not known. This follows from the previous error message that implied that there was no declaration.

> Initializing 'double' with an expression of incompatible type 'id'

This one is a little harder. Since the method declaration of `scrollThresholdForPasscodeScroll` was not seen the compiler makes an assumption that the return type is an `id` yet it is assigned to a double.

So, it seems they all come down to the declaration not being seen and that implies that perhaps the header file (.h) was not imported. Check that it is imported correctly or add the import.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Zaph, but what I'm trying to figure out is why I'm unable to import the SBLockScreenNotificationScrollView file or why it isn't included.

Comment: @Nate I've read your answer and I'm looking into trying to dump the headers myself. In the private frameworks directory though, the springboard framework isn't included

Comment: @Nate ok so I've dumped the springboard headers and included them but now I'm getting errors when trying run. it seems every import in the headers is broken

Comment: @Nate now I'm getting a linker error. How can I link to springboard since it is an app?

Comment: @Nate I understand. thanks for your help. if you'll post an answer explaining what you said in the commments, I'll accept it